# Drag and drop a file is not working in IE 11 over iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-11, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm working on a basic drag and drop functionality and it working fine in other browsers but not in IE 11. I'm calling following html code with iframe in another project.

It is working fine without iframe but not with iframe. Can anyone give a solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Upload</title>
<meta name="description" content="File Upload ">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">  
    <table><tbody> <tr><td><span id="upload" >
                          <span>Upload</span><input id="fileupload" type="file" name="fileupload">
                    </span></td><td id="filename"></td><td id="percent" style="padding-left: 35px;"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/master/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
 <script
    src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).bind('drop dragover', function(e) {
            /* e.preventDefault(); */
        });
        if(typeof window.parent.fileid  == 'undefined'){
            window.parent.fileid = "";
        }            
        var params = // some prams
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType : 'json',
            formData : params,
            url : '${contextpath}/upload', 
            autoUpload: true,
        });         
        $('#fileupload')
        .bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {          
            //uploaded successfully
       }, 100);
        }).bind('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        // upload is fail
        })  
    });

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It seems it is not recognizing the drop area (iframe content). Straight away it asking to leave the page ?, In that case do we need to write any mouseove or mouseenter events at parent window ?

Comment: Try adding `forceIframeTransport: true` to the options you pass to `fileupload` function. Please go through this documentation first https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads

Comment: What's exactly 'not working'? I tested it on IE11 (after several code re-arrangements, copy/paste didin't worked), and the script sent a `POST` request to the server with the file.

Comment: @muecas: The browser is saying 'Are you sure you want to leave this page ?' When I'm trying drop a file on this iframe area in IE11.  I think 'drag enter' event is not firing at this moment. I tried in different ways but not solved.

Comment: Can you add to your question  the exact code you are using? The published one has several errors.

Comment: Hi All, It resolved after I changed compatibility to IE10 while my application is loading.

Answer (score 5):

I tested your code with some of rearrangement and i noticed the browser says 'Are you sure you want to leave this page ?'. You can resolve this issue by some ways such as

1. you may change the browser compatibility from IE11 to IE10
2. Yoy need to set 'forceIframeTransport: true' option to force all browser to make use of the iframe transport module for file uploads and set redirect option to retrieve the drop result

your file upload function should be

```js
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType : 'json',
            formData : params,
            url : '${contextpath}/upload', 
            autoUpload: true,
            forceIframeTransport: true,
            'redirect',
        });
```